# obfuscate a Java file by Python Program

Tags: java, python

im trying to build a simple Encryption in python(Im not even sure that can called as Encryption)
i want the program to take a .java file and change the varibels to random staff from text file
example:

```
public static int IDS=100;
public int ID;
public String name;
public String Password;
public int score;

public int nothing()
{
    return ID;
}
```

will change to:

```
public static int OOA=100;
public int AAO;
public String AOA;
public String OCC;
public int OBA;

public int OKA()
{
    return AAO;
}
```

and the text file contian:

```
OOA AAO AOA OCC OBA OKA
```

i thought about using Replace(), but how do i detect the Varibale?

Comment: If you're trying to obfuscate source code, simply changing the variable names is a really poor attempt to do so. Most of us are already in the profession of being able to understand code with terrible naming.

Comment: You need a (source code) parser & lexer to identify what is a variable identifier. There's probably some libraries that can handle the hard part, but I'm not sure why you want to do that?

Comment: It's called obfuscation. And you will need a Java parser to do it (remember each variable has its scope).

Comment: You need a dictionary of all classes and methods as well. Not only variables are being replaced

Comment: While you can of course experiment with obfuscation, as others already stated this can get quite complex. There are several obfuscators available for java which can also be used during build process.

Comment: @CoryKramer thanks you :), so what way of encryption you recommand?